# How to compare two list,ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I have two list and wanna know which items are in the fist one and arn't in second one,

```
List<int> viewphonenumid = new List<int>();
List<int?> DtoPhonenumId = new List<int?>();
```

For instance  viewphonenumid  has {1,2,3,4,5,6} and DtoPhonenumId has{3,4,5,6} and I wanna have {1,2} in a new list.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newList= viewphonenumid.Except(DtoPhonenumId).ToList();
```

You also can specify comparer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Good mention about possibility to specify comparer, it is extremely useful when compare complex object or partially filled objects or projections

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var newList= viewphonenumid.Where(v =>! DtoPhonenumId.Contains(v)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Enumerable.Except
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx

Something like this

```
(new List<int> {1,2,3,4}).Except(new List<int> {3,4})
```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
List<int> result = new List<int>();
foreach(int element in viewphonenumid)
    if(!DtoPhonenumId.Contains(element))
        result.Add(element);
```

I hope that help